# Dell Inspiron 20 3043 not booting into Windows 7 Setup

Tags: windows-7, bios, uefi

As you can see from the title of my post, I'm trying to boot an Inspiron 20 3043 AIO into the Windows 7 setup.  I'm trying to downgrade it from 10 to 7 since most of my work still uses 7 as opposed to 8/8.1 or 10.

I'm having some issues trying to get into setup though.

I've updated the BIOS of the system to the latest revision, and no matter what I do, I can't get it to go into the setup.  I first tried the combinations of having the secure boot option disabled and the load legacy option also set to disabled.  Once it got through the initial loading of the files, it got stuck on the starting Windows screen with a giant red bar across the top of the screen.

I then tried setting the load legacy option rom setting to enabled, and it failed again.  This time, it presented me with a BSOD saying "The BIOS in this system is not fully ACPI compliant.  Please contact your system vendor for an updated BIOS."

Both of these things happen regardless of the media I use, whether it would be from a Windows 7 DVD in an external DVD drive, or a USB flash drive.

Is there something that I need to do that I'm forgetting about, or am I out of luck for downgrading to 7 on this thing?

Answer (score -1):

Current BIOS settings, use the Windows UEFI Secure Boot Settings. If you want it to downgrade, you need to modify the UEFI root settings

Comment: By which, do you mean compatibility mode?